# Desktop Sharing Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: remote-desktop

When I click on Desktop Sharing in System Settings, all that happens is System Settings disappears.  This is a VMWare Virtual Machine, but I don't think that's coming into play. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Wayland desktop architecture, then desktop sharing is not implemented yet. It will be using pipewire in the future. Have you tried logging in with x server x11?